# Infinite Loop and Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeedaec488)

Tags: ios, debugging, swift5, xcode11.4

I'm getting a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeedaec488) at the array for tabBar.viewControllers = [cameraVC, galleryVC] and in my console I'm getting my username endlessly printed out, which comes from a different class. The first code snippet shows where the thread was shown:

```
func addTabBar() {
    let cameraVC = HomeViewController()
    let galleryVC = GalleryViewController()

    let tabBarItem1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Camera", image: UIImage(named: "camera-icon")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "blueCamera-icon")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal))
    let tabBarItem2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Gallery", image: UIImage(named: "gallery-icon")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "blueGallery-icon")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal))



    cameraVC.tabBarItem = tabBarItem1
    galleryVC.tabBarItem = tabBarItem2
    tabBarItem2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)

    tabBar.viewControllers = [cameraVC, galleryVC]

    self.view.addSubview(tabBar.view)
}
```

This is my second code snippet with all the functions defined where I'm getting my print statement for the username endlessly repeated in the console:

```
@IBAction func signUpTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    //validate the fields
    let error = validateFields()
    
    if error != nil {
        //something's wrong, show error message
        showError(error!)
    }
    else {
        
        //create trimmed data
        let userName = userNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        //create the user
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result,err) in
            
            //check for errors
            if err != nil {
                //error creating user
                self.showError(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Error creating user")
            }
            else {
                    let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                    changeRequest?.displayName = userName
                    print(userName)
                changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in print ("Username not created") }

                //transition to home screen
                self.saveLoggedState()
                self.transitionHome()
            }
        }
    }
}
func showError(_ message:String){
    
    errorLabel.text = message
    errorLabel.alpha = 1
}
func saveLoggedState() {
    
    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    def.set(true, forKey: "is_authenticated")
    def.synchronize()
    
}
func transitionHome() {
    
    let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC!)
    self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

I hope that's enough code! I'm really confused about what the problem is and previous stack overflow posts haven't been helpful. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit 1: I'm also implementing a side menu in my home controller. The code for it looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.backgroundColor = color
    view.backgroundColor = color
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}

// Table
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].rawValue
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.backgroundColor = color
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    // Relay to delegate about menu item selection
    let selectedItem = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    delegate?.didSelectMenuItem(named: selectedItem)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func addTabBar() {
   let cameraVC = HomeViewController()
   let galleryVC = GalleryViewController()
}
```

I guess it's a typo, you create HomeViewController inside a HomeViewController, which causes an infinite loop, and I think your Auth is called inside viewViewAppear/didLoad, so it triggers endlessly until you Stack overflow.

If that's not the case, I guess your HomeViewController triggers signUpTapped, and then on user creation it goes back to HomeViewController (which triggers signUpTapped again), so a recursion without an end.

Comment: Hi Vitalii, I originally created a different view controller for my cameraVC, but I also have a side menu to navigate to different view controllers. When I create a new view controller, my side menu wasn't working. Is there a way to still include the homeVC or is that impossible? Do I have to create a new view controller? Thanks!

Comment: You have to remove recursive calls from the code, look at this example:
 - You have a HomeViewController (main screen), inside of it you have 2 tabs (CameraVC, GalleryVC). But the problems comes when you try to create HomeVC as a tab inside HomeVC, then the second HomeVC would create another HomeVC tab, so an infinite loop. You can include homeVC, but you have to stop creating them at some point

Comment: I see now, but how would I be able to stop creating them? Sorry about all the questions! The answers may seem fairly obvious, but I'm a newbie at Swift and I don't know much about how to end recursion. Thank you!

Comment: In your example I don't think you ever need to embed HomeViewController as a Tab, because it will have another tabs inside of it and it will look ugly. If you need a third tab - just add a third different tab with content that you need. HomeViewController should only have UITabViewController (basically be a box for your tabs)

Comment: So it should be like this
         HomeViewController contains
 GalleryVC  +   CameraVC +  AdditionalDataVC

And this way by transitionHome you shouldn't create additional HomeViewController, because you will call it from HomeViewController already

Comment: Ahhh, I think I got it now. So, just to confirm, my HomeViewController will be an 'empty view controller' with just a tab view controller with other view controllers attached. Should I still keep the transitionHome function because it's going to a tabBar controller? And would I still do the same for my side menu even though other view controllers will be displayed? For reference, I will attach the code for side menu in my post

Comment: If you have UiViewControllers other than HomeViewController, and if you call your Auth method outside HomeViewController, then yes you should still transition to it. 

For side menu look at this example, I have UITabBarController (HomeVC in my app), and MenuVC, which I create and transition to every time the app is called. You just basically have to insert that into view hierarchy, whether it is with UINavigationController or addSubview
https://gist.github.com/sanstorik/ba3bc32adb3272a67260f02f57fc5772

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I overrode the loadView method but forgot to add super.loadView()